# Как добавить данные в модель?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Есть форма на которой я подписываюсь на почтовые отправления

```
<%= form_for(@subs) do |f| %>
            <div class="col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
                <%=f.label :email, class: 'sr-only' %>
                <%=f.text_field :email, class: 'form-control animation-1' %>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
              <%= f.submit 'Подписаться', class: 'btn btn-secondary animation text-uppercase' %>
            </div>
          <% end %>
```

Однако данные не заносятся в базу. Как отправить данные в контроллер из этого представления?

```
class SubscriberController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @subs = Subscriber.new(post_params)
    if @subs.save
      redirect_to main_path, notice: 'Ваш емейл успешно добавлен в список рассылки'
    else
      flash[:alert] = "There was a problem creating post"
      render :new
    end

  end
  def new
    @subs  = Subscriber.new
  end
  private

  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:id, :email)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вот так:

```
<%= form_for :subscriber do |f| %>
            <div class="col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
                <%=f.label :email, class: 'sr-only' %>
                <%=f.text_field :email, class: 'form-control animation-1' %>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
              <%= f.submit 'Подписаться', class: 'btn btn-secondary animation text-uppercase' %>
            </div>
          <% end %>
```

Контроллер:

```
     def create
        @subs = Subscriber.new(subscriber_params)
        if @subs.save
          redirect_to main_path, notice: 'Ваш емейл успешно добавлен в список рассылки'
        else
          flash[:alert] = "There was a problem creating post"
          render :new
        end

      end
      def new
      end
  private

  def subscriber_params
    params.require(:subscriber).permit(:email)
  end
```